# jQuery this or closest syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML with couple of tags and paragraphs I should assign class name to paragraphs that has single quote in it. `“`

I tried using the following way

```
$('p').each(function() {                                      
            if($("p:contains('“')").length) {
$(this).replaceWith(function () {
return "<div class='quotetext'>" + $(this).html() + "</div>";
});
}
});
```

But this is overwriting all p tags. I also tried using closest like `$(this).closest.replaceWith(function () {`

but still no luck. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
$('p:contains("“")').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith(function () {
        return "<div class='quotetext'>" + $(this).html() + "</div>";
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0kuL6k0z/)

Your `if` condition in the each loop will be evaluated to true if at least 1 `p` has the content `“`, not just the currently looped one, so the `replaceWith` will get executed for every `p` element in the page.

Instead you can iterate through only those `p` elements which has `“` as its content as shown above.

Comment: Error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score 0):

Some simple jquery and a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fxomsfna/

This loops through the paragraph tags, tests their contents for one double quote (more or less will fail) and adds the `has_quote` class to any that match.

```
$('p').each(function (i, el) {
    var p = $(el);
    if (/^[^"]*"[^"]*$/.test(p.text())) {
      p.addClass('has_quote');
    }
});
```